# Powershell script to see if computer is set to go to sleep or display is turned off?

Tags: powershell, sleep

I'm looking for a Powershell script that will display computers in our AD environment...and I'd like to see if they have a time limit before they go to sleep or display is turned off. The reason I'm asking...setup WSUS in our environment and some computers aren't checking in. Wondering if they're going to sleep during scheduled install.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hello and Welcome to SO, We are Developers Helping Developers Develop!
So whats a Developer? Anyone who is Coding,Scripting  who wants a Second, Third or Hundred extra eyes on a project.
Please post code that you have tried or Code you are working on that is not working for you.

Comment: @boxdog Haven't tried anything yet. Been searching on the web but haven't found anything.